# Error while running Victoria II on wine

Tags: wine

I installed Victoria II and tried to run it but it gave me this error? how to fix it?

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x009b82d1).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:009b82d1 ESP:0159cc08 EBP:0159d9d0 EFLAGS:00010202(  R- --  I   - - - )
 EAX:00000001 EBX:00000000 ECX:0159cbf0 EDX:00000000
 ESI:0159ccb8 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x0159cc08:  00000010 0159dbe4 00000000 04bc2e00
0x0159cc18:  04bc6340 7bc5025f 714a9cc8 0159cc40
0x0159cc28:  0159cc98 7b061739 04bc2e00 0159d648
0x0159cc38:  04be1f40 7b061739 00000000 0159cc78
0x0159cc48:  00000014 0000001f 0159d648 00000040
0x0159cc58:  0159cc98 69859ae9 80000001 00000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x009b82d1 in v2game (+0x5b82d1) (0x0159d9d0)
  1 0x009d8e1a in v2game (+0x5d8e1a) (0x0159def4)
  2 0x0097cbfe in v2game (+0x57cbfe) (0x0159fea0)
  3 0x00ab0f3e in v2game (+0x6b0f3e) (0x0159ff30)
  4 0x7b629ee0 in kernel32 (+0x29ee0) (0x0159ff48)
  5 0x7bc5c6e7 in ntdll (+0x5c6e7) (0x0159ff5c)
  6 0x7bc5cef0 RtlCreateUserThread(entry=00AB0F91, arg=7FFD1000) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\thread.c:306] in ntdll (0x0159ffec)
0x009b82d1 v2game+0x5b82d1: movl    0x0(%edi),%edx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (81 modules)
PE  00370000-00399000   Deferred        lua5.1
PE  003a0000-003c6000   Deferred        tbb
PE  003d0000-003df000   Deferred        psapi
PE  00400000-01492000   Export          v2game
PE  018a0000-01abf000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  01ac0000-01f38000   Deferred        ole32
PE  01f40000-0208d000   Deferred        combase
PE  02090000-022a3000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  022b0000-02538000   Deferred        msvcr80
PE  02540000-02872000   Deferred        quartz
PE  02880000-028e2000   Deferred        msacm32
PE  028f0000-02957000   Deferred        msvfw32
PE  02960000-02de3000   Deferred        comctl32
PE  02df0000-030b3000   Deferred        msvcp100
PE  030c0000-0321e000   Deferred        d3d9
PE  03ba0000-03c24000   Deferred        winex11
PE  04dc0000-04dd2000   Deferred        tbbmalloc
PE  10000000-10006000   Deferred        lua51
PE  3b400000-3b41f000   Deferred        steam_api
PE  61c40000-61c63000   Deferred        userenv
PE  61fc0000-620b3000   Deferred        dinput8
PE  62500000-6290a000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE  63500000-635d2000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_47
PE  636c0000-63990000   Deferred        msvcr100
PE  643c0000-64449000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE  64a80000-64ad8000   Deferred        win32u
PE  65680000-658fc000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  66080000-66179000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  66640000-6665b000   Deferred        version
PE  667c0000-66806000   Deferred        shcore
PE  67500000-67553000   Deferred        imm32
PE  67c00000-67d37000   Deferred        dsound
PE  68580000-68872000   Deferred        d3dx9_41
PE  68880000-68d6a000   Deferred        user32
PE  69840000-6993b000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  69f40000-69fc4000   Deferred        d3dxof
PE  6aac0000-6ad9c000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE  6aec0000-6b06f000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  6bbc0000-6bc57000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6cc80000-6e016000   Deferred        wined3d
PE  6f240000-6f3bc000   Deferred        winmm
PE  70d80000-70e20000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  71080000-710a8000   Deferred        hid
PE  71400000-720af000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7a800000-7acc1000   Deferred        opengl32
PE  7b000000-7b52c000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b759000   Dwarf-4         kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bebc000   Dwarf-4         ntdll
ELF 7d000000-7d005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7e086000-7e08e000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7e08e000-7e09b000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7e09b000-7e0b0000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7e0b0000-7e0b5000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e0b5000-7e0c4000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e0c4000-7e0d2000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e0d2000-7e0da000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e0da000-7e0df000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7e0df000-7e0ed000   Deferred        libmd.so.0
ELF 7e0ed000-7e105000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7e105000-7e10d000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e10d000-7e113000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e113000-7e141000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e141000-7e293000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e293000-7e2aa000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e2b6000-7e2bc000   Deferred        ws2_32.so
ELF 7e2be000-7e34a000   Deferred        winex11.so
ELF 7e34a000-7e3ec000   Deferred        opengl32.so
ELF 7e554000-7e584000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e584000-7e5d4000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e5d4000-7e5f7000   Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
ELF 7e5f7000-7e637000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7e637000-7e704000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e704000-7e877000   Deferred        win32u.so
ELF 7e877000-7ea00000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF 7ec12000-7ec20000   Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
ELF 7ec20000-7ec3e000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ec3e000-7ed46000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF f7b50000-f7c00000   Deferred        ntdll.so
ELF f7c00000-f7e35000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7e36000-f7e40000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF f7edf000-f7f17000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio    name (all IDs are in hex)
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0     
    00000040    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    00000078    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    0000008c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000c4    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000d0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000fc    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000114    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000134    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000064 MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe
    00000068    0     
    000000b4    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    000000b8    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    000000bc    0     wine_threadpool_timer_queue
    000000c0    0     
0000006c svchost.exe
    00000070    0     
    0000007c    0     
    00000080    0     wine_sechost_service
00000084 winedevice.exe
    00000088    0     
    00000090    0     
    00000094    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000098    0     
    0000009c    0     
    000000a0    0     
    00000128    0     
000000a8 winedevice.exe
    000000ac    0     
    000000c8    0     
    000000cc    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000d4    0     
    000000d8    0     
    000000e0    0     
    000000e4    0     
    000000f0    0     
000000f4 plugplay.exe
    000000f8    0     
    00000100    0     
    00000104    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000108    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
0000010c svchost.exe
    00000110    0     
    00000118    0     
    0000011c    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000120    0     
    0000015c    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    00000160    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
0000012c rpcss.exe
    00000130    0     
    00000138    0     
    0000013c    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000140    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    00000144    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000035c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000344 (D) E:\Victoria II\v2game.exe
    00000348    0 <== 
    00000374    0     
0000034c explorer.exe
    00000350    0     
    00000354    0     
    00000358    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
0000036c conhost.exe
    00000370    0     
System information:
    Wine build: wine-8.0.2
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.19.0-50-generic
```

Comment: Hello an welcome to AskUbuntu: From the context I assume, that you are having an issue with an Windows application running on `wine` -> you should consider asking for help at https://www.winehq.org/

Comment: Application specific problem, not Ubuntu specific

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Comment: @SimonSudler I was under the clear impression that we support using Wine on Ubuntu. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @vidarlo: Yes, that is true. However this error is coming from the application `Victoria II` in combination with `wine`. At least `Victoria II` is not Ubuntu and winehq offers help for exactly this kind of problems